# Obter dados na view do Django

Tags: python, django

Na hora do cadastro de um novo usuário ele escolhe de qual grupo faz parte por meio de um select. Cada grupo possui um responsável, como faço para pegar o email desse responsável para enviar um email de pedido de autorização de acesso?

Nesse código eu envio email mas para o email que o usuário preencheu e não para o responsável do grupo que foi escolhido.

models.py

```
class Grupo(models.Model):

    grupo = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    divisao = models.ForeignKey(Divisao)
    responsavel = models.ForeignKey(User)

    @property
      def get_responsavel(self):
        return self.responsavel
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.grupo


class Perfil(User):
    telefone = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ramal = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    data_inicio = models.DateField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    data_fim = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    e_responsavel = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    vinculo = models.ForeignKey(Vinculo)
    grupos = models.ForeignKey(Grupo)
    divisao = models.ForeignKey(Divisao)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

views.py

```
def cadastro(request, group_id=None):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        formulario = form.save()

        if form.is_valid():
            formulario.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
            formulario.save()

            # Envio de email
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            message = render_to_string('acc_active_email.html', {
                'user': formulario,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(formulario.pk)),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(formulario),
            })
            mail_subject = 'Novo usuario no sistema'


            group = Grupo.objects.get(pk=group_id)
            responsavel = group.get_responsavel()
            to_email = responsavel.email
            email = EmailMessage(mail_subject, message, to=[to_email])
            email.send()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/cadastro/login/')

    else:
        form = UserForm()
    return render(request, 'cadastro.html', {
        'form': form,

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá!

Você pode fazer um filtro, para pegar o grupo que o usuário escolheu, você pode fazer assim, precisa pegar o id do grupo pelo envio do formulário, ai você faz o filtro:

Para pegar o moderador, você pode fazer um decorator no seu model de grupo

Ex:

```
class Grupo(models.Model):
    grupo = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    divisao = models.ForeignKey(Divisao)
    responsavel = models.ForeignKey(User)

    @property
    def get_responsavel(self):
        return self.responsavel

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.grupo
```

com isso você consegue pegar o moderador do grupo

```
group = Grupo.objects.get(pk=group_id)
responsavel = group.get_responsavel()
responsavel.email
```

É uma simples dica, mas caso tenha mais dúvidas, seria interessante ver como está seus models, para pegar os relacionamentos corretos

Comment: Atualizei colocando o models, como você pode observar eu uso um único formulário, o UserForm e preciso pegar o responsavel_id dentro da classe grupos e com isso ir pra classe Perfil pegar o email pelo id desse responsável

Comment: Olá Bianca, verifique que eu atualizei a resposta, vê se você entende?

Comment: Oi José, obrigada pela resposta, porém retornou a seguinte mensagem: Grupo matching query does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Na instancia de model o retorno do email pode ser especificado por

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.email
```

Se houver um aviso do tipo:

> *str*_ returned non-string

Corrija o retorno que  não é um string.

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.email)
```

Em User, possui o cadastro email,nome e por ai vai... (correto ?)
E logo indica qual tipo de pessoa e a qual  grupo esta.

E pelo grupo quer recuperar o email do usuário em uma devida classificação.

```
usuario_logago = request.user.id
Grupo.objects.filter(responsavel_id=usuario_logago)
```

ou

```
Grupo.objects.filter(responsavel__id__exact=usuario_logago)
```

Pelo model que registra o usuario esta usando a função que retorno o email

```
def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

o retorno sera apresentado:

> <QuerySet [<Grupo: admin@localhost.com>, <Grupo:
> admin@localhost.com>]>

Se a pessoa estiver em outros grupos serão apresentados os emails.

No caso do uso do lookups,poderia recuperar passando o email no entanto não se aplica ao que precisa, mas fica a referencia

request.user.id : retorna o id do usuario logado
request.user : recupera o nome do usuario logado

o recurso lookups, recupera altera apaga registro.

Na documentação é mencionado como utilizar o lookups pare recuperar dados vindo de outra tb referenciada.

[field-lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups)

Espero que tenha ajudado, qualquer coisa só perguntas :)